# array_sum PHP wrong result

Tags: php, array-sum

the result of this should be zero!

```
echo array_sum([-61.50,50.00,10.50,1.00,0.00,50.00,-16.73,-20.00,-55.75,42.48]);
```

Why is giving -7.105427357601E-15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try `round()`, you will get the same result.

```
echo round(array_sum([-61.50,50.00,10.50,1.00,0.00,50.00,-16.73,-20.00,-55.75,42.48]));
```

Comment: but i need the floating points... 
round(array_sum([-61.50,50.00,10.50,1.00,0.00,50.00,-16.73,-20.00,-55.75,42.48]),2); works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Because floating point values (which you have here when you use decimals) are not exact. [They're approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

The error in that approximation comes out to `-7.105427357601E-15` when summing these values.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of floats. If you want to calculate something with precision 2 (for this example) you should use something like this:

```
$el = [-61.50,50.00,10.50,1.00,0.00,50.00,-16.73,-20.00,-55.75,42.48];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($el as $e) {
    $sum += $e * 100;
}

echo $sum / 100;
```

You should never trust to float values. Another example from Javascript (Google developer Console):

[image]

Comment: yeah... but javascript is know from being dump in math! Wasn't expecting this from PHP